# how does this code works for checking the permissions?

Tags: android, permissions

Post api 23 we need to dynamically check the permission . 
according to my understanding the flow should be like this

**1. is permission granted by the user? 
if no -->  we can either show request dialogue box or we should not (because of his of selection of "don't sow again" in the past .**

if yes --> perform the functionality for which the permission was needed.

Now the code according to the google docs is :

```
    // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

        // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
}
```

*shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(). This method returns true if the app has requested this permission previously and the user denied the request.
Note: If the user turned down the permission request in the past and chose the Don't ask again option in the permission request system dialog, this method returns false. The method also returns false if a device policy prohibits the app from having that permission.*

Now according to me there should be a "!" operator in the second if statement . 
Please tell me where am I wrong?

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: @Adan_SL the question is --  should there be a "!" operator in the second if statement ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a use of ! operator in the second if statement. That if condition returns true if you have the permission. The functions you want to perform with that permission should be written inside that if statement. The else case is executed if the if returns false, which will happen when the user denies permission or the user has selected "Don't ask again" option in the past.